# Yandex map подмена координат в эмуляторе

Tags: android, yandex-maps-api, геолокация, android-emulator

Использую для работы с картой Yandex MapKit, хочу сымитировать движение по карте с помощью эмулятора, но при добавление координаты в эмулятор, на Yandex карте ничего не отображается, как добиться того, что бы Yandex карте приходили координаты в эмуляторе?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как вы пробовали?

Comment: Добавил, как пробовал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может кому поможет, что бы оно работала, на дивайсе эмулятора должен быть установлен Play Store